# What does "just look" mean in Judged?

Tags: meaning, ziyad-marar, judged

In *Judged* by Ziyad Marar, the author was discussing why it's harder for women to be both nice and in control, the twin pillars of good reputaion:

> It turns out that while the blend of being nice and control is in tension for most people, and hard for anyone to achieve that intersection in the Venn diagram, that middle way tends to be even less available to women according to some telling research by Frank Flynn and Cameron Anderson using a Harvard Business School study about a successful Silicon Valley venture capitalist named Heidi Roizen. Students were split into two groups. Half were given the original case study, and the other half were given the study but using the name Howard instead of Heidi. This was the only change, so every other detail of the case study was identical. The students were surveyed on their attitudes to the person depicted in the case. The groups found Heidi and Howard equally competent, but Howard was deemed more likeable, genuine and kind while Heidi was seen as aggressive, selfish and power hungry, and not ‘the type of person you would want to hire or work for’. It seems that Heidi Roizen faces that double bind of deciding to be a successful entrepreneur or a successful woman, which might have something to do with the hero being, typically, a male figure. It’s not within the scope of this book to explore the phenomenon of sexism in detail, but I’ll note that when my teenage daughter Anna is asked why she is happy to use the label ‘feminist’ to describe herself unlike many in her age group, her response is, **‘Just look!’**.

What's exactly meant by "Just look!"? does it mean "just an outer appearance"? If so, what does it have to do with this context?